# Mysql multiple join table insert won't working when apply custom autoincrement

Tags: mysql, database

Say i have 3 or 4 table which some table are connected with parent table. I want to submit data to these table at same time.

```
Table: table1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| table1Id(AI)(PK) |  blah1 | blah2 | blah3 | blah3 | blah4 | [....]
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: table2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| table2Id(AI)(PK) | clah1 |  clah2 | clah3 | clah4 | [....] | table1Id (FK)
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: table3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| table3Id(AI)(PK) | flah1 |  flah2 | flah3 | flah4 | [....] | table1Id (FK)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And My database SQL Code is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
  `table1Id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blah1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `blah2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `blah3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `blah4` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table1Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table2` (
  `table2Id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clah1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `clah2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `clah3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `clah4` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `table1Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table2Id`),
  INDEX `FK_table1_table2_idx` (`table1Id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table2_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`table1Id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`table1` (`table1Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table3` (
  `table3Id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flah1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `flah2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `flah3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `flah4` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `table1Id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table3Id`),
  INDEX `FK_table3_table1_idx` (`table1Id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_table3_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`table1Id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`table1` (`table1Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

### SQL INSERT QUERY (Updated):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4, blah5)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO table2 (clah1, clah2, clah3, clah4, clah5, table1Id)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());

INSERT INTO table3 (flah1, flah2, flah3, flah4, flah5, table1Id)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Everything working correctly by above code but if i apply custom auto_increment on table1 Table then Insert query shows me error which is:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails

## Auto Increment Code

```
ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT=300;
```

How do i fix this ? I want to submit all data to both table1 - table3 Table.

I tried also transaction commit, this also won't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the third query, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will provide the value for `table2Id` not `table1Id`. However while the auto increment is not modified, both table1 and table2 starts from 1. So Foreign key verification succeeds.

For example on a fresh table:

- The first query will insert with table1Id 300.
- The second query will
  insert with table2Id 1 and populate table1Id col with 300 which is
  valid.
- The third query will populate table1Id col with 1 which is
  invalid.

What you can do is, keep the LAST_INSERT_ID() in a variable after the first query and use it in rest of the queries.

Full code for insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SET @LID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO table2 (clah1, clah2, clah3, clah4, table1Id)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @LID);

INSERT INTO table3 (flah1, flah2, flah3, flah4, table1Id)
     VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @LID);
```

P.S.: I have modified the insert queries a bit more as they contained some invalid columns.

Comment: I applied to this on Codeigniter , now work like charm :) @Mohaimenul Haque Adnan